# Is there any ready-made tool available to generate Setup Scripts for Database Provider for Microsoft Sync

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-ce-4

I am working with Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1, MS SQL Server 2008 * MS SQL CE 4.0 ...

Is there any ready-made tool available to generate Setup Scripts for Database Provider for Microsoft Sync

please visit below link so you come to know that what i want

please expand section "Custom Change Tracking for Offline-Only Scenarios"

Currently i have to write this SQL Script for each and every table but i have more then 100 tables in my application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726041.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have "offline" clients running on SQL CE that need to sync tables with a central SQL Server 2008 database I would recommend you avail yourself of the Sync Framework Toolkit (previously touted as Microsoft Sync Framework 4.0)

The toolkit aims principally to support 2-way synchronisation between non-Microsoft clients and SQL Server.

The toolkit already comes with an SqlCeOfflineSyncProvider implemented and you get the source code so you can mod it to your requirements.

It comes with a console (SyncSvcUtil.exe) and a GUI (SyncSvcUtilUI.exe) utility to generate all the change tracking stored procs and tracking tables in your SQL Server DB for the tables that you wish to synchronise. It is easy to execute this sync table provisioning from code too.

Download it [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e).

Also, the compiled help CHM documentation is also quite good.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the provisioning API should be able to do that for you. see: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://social.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494.aspx)

Sync Framework by default doestn work with SQL CE 4 but you can make it work, see: [Sync Framework and SQL Compact 4 (Yes, You Can!)](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/sync-framework-and-sql-compact-4-yes-you-can/)

you can also use SQL Server Compact Tool for generating the provisioning and synchronization code, see: [SQL Server Compact Toolbox Sync Framework support](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/sql-server-compact-toolbox-sync-framework-support/)

the Sync Toolkit is primarily designed for non-MS client platforms or those that cant have the full Sync Framework SDK (Silverlight, Windows Phone, iOS, etc...), you have full MS stack, so you can stick with Sync Framework itself.